# Where I am wrong in using mod $p$ irreducible test?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Mod p irreducibility test : Let $p$ be a prime an suppose that $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ with $\deg f(x) \geq 1$. Let $f_1(x)$ be the polynomial in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ obtained from $f(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients of $f(x)$ modulo $p$. If $f_1(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\deg f_1(x)=\deg f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

For the function $f(x)=x^3+1$, if I consider modulo 5, then this function is irreducible over $Z_5[x]$ as $f(0)=1,f(1)=2,f(2)=4,f(3)=3\ and\ f(4)=3$, hence by mod irreducibility test, it should be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.But since $x^3+1$ has a root $-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ so it will be reducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I am not getting where I am wrong in using this mod irreducible test, as I am getting the function irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ which is actually reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: By the Factor Theorem $\,x+1\mid x^3+1\,$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ and by universality this factorization persists in every ring. Your error is that $\,f(4) = f(-1) =0\neq 3\,$ in $\Bbb Z_5\ \ $

Comment: Just in case it is not clear from the comment/answer, there is an arithmetic error, $f(4) = 4^3 + 1 = 65 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The factorization
$(x+1)(1-x+x^2)$ still works in ${\bf F}_5[x]$
(it can also be written as $(x+1)(1+4x+x^2)$).  So it is reducible in ${\bf F}_5[x]$ as well as in ${\bf Q}[x]$.